# snakemake fails due to jobscript not found

Tags: latency, snakemake

I'm running snakemake on fairly large workflows. Somewhat randomly I get errors like

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/prog/Python/3.7.9-foss-2018a/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/prog/Python/3.7.9-foss-2018a/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<home>/.pip/CentOS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 1069, in _wait_for_jobs
    status = job_status(active_job)
  File "<home>/.pip/CentOS/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 1051, in job_status
    os.remove(active_job.jobscript)<current working dir>/.snakemake/tmp.0w7jh5bc/snakejob.<name of rule>.6868.sh'
```

It happens somewhat randomly and restarting the workflow usually resolves the problem. I think this might be due to filesystem latency, however the `latency-wait` flag seems to work only on output files. Is there a way to make snakemake wait for jobscripts as well?

Comment: Can you post a bit more information? E.g. the code of the rule(s) causing it, the snakemake command line you use... Can you reduce the pipeline to a small set of rules reproducing the problem?

Comment: Idk which version you use, but trying the newest version might help?

Comment: I have a hard time to come up with a minimal example where the problem still occurs. Regarding versions: actually there is no problem up to snakemake 5.25 but only for the newer versions